# Comment Line Dissapears After Rewriting a Node

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, automated-refactoring

I was writing simple refactoring and noticed a strange thing. The comment line before the node I am rewriting disappears after refactoring. Also comments after the node in question are transferred inside the node and break the indentation in the new place. This is very strange and I want to ask if it is a bug in jdt or I did something wrong and oblivious.

For example my code suppose to refactor if-else statements in a way that the shortest branch would appear first.
when I try to refactor this:

```java
    // pre
    if(a==6) { 
        a = 5;
        return false;
    } else { 
        a++;
    }
    //post
```

I get this:

```java
    if (!(a==6)) { 
        a++;
    }
    //post 
else { 
        a = 5;
        return false;
    }
```

The relevant snippet where the refactoring is done:

```java
protected ASTRewrite createRewrite(CompilationUnit cu, SubProgressMonitor pm) {
    pm.beginTask("Creating rewrite operation...", 1);

    final AST ast = cu.getAST();
    final ASTRewrite rewrite = ASTRewrite.create(ast);

    cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
        public boolean visit(IfStatement node) {
            if (node.getStartPosition() > selection.getOffset() + selection.getLength() || node.getStartPosition() < selection.getOffset())
                return true;

            if (node.getElseStatement() == null)
                return true;

            int thenCount = countNodes(node.getThenStatement());
            int elseCount = countNodes(node.getElseStatement());

            if(thenCount <= elseCount)
                return true;

            IfStatement newnode = ast.newIfStatement(); 
            PrefixExpression neg = negateExpression(ast, rewrite, node.getExpression());    
            newnode.setExpression(neg);

            newnode.setThenStatement((org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Statement) rewrite.createMoveTarget(node.getElseStatement()));
            newnode.setElseStatement((org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Statement) rewrite.createMoveTarget(node.getThenStatement()));   

            rewrite.replace(node, newnode, null);                       
            return true;
        }
    });
    pm.done();
    return rewrite;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `// pre` comment goes away because the parser considers it to be part of the next statement (represented by `node`), which you replace with `newNode`.  When `node` goes away, so does the attached comment.

still thinking about why the `// post` ends up where it does... Try replacing the newNode before setting its then and else statements

Comment: I thought that comment lines are not part of the AST , I also was not able to see them in the AST viewer. Anyway, how can I copy the comment into newnode? I can't find any member method of Node that looks like it can get/set a comment.

Comment: The latest AST sees three types of comments, one of which is Javadoc.  The BodyDeclaration (superclass of MethodDeclaration and others) class has a getJavadoc() method that returns a Javadoc instance.  Other kinds of comments (including LineComment - which you have) have to be retrieved from the CompilationUnit using getCommentList()