# JDT preserve comments

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, automated-refactoring

JDT uses some internal smarts to associate comments with ASTNode. This means that if you replace or remove a specific ASTNode, the "associated" comments will be removed (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593015/comment-line-dissapears-after-rewriting-a-node)). This works on most occasions but I run into a fairly obnoxious problem:

I am trying to rewrite code of the style:

```
private classA variableX;
```

to

```
private classZ variableX;
```

Normally I can do that by simply replacing the Type node corresponding to "classA" with a similar Type node (corresponding to "classZ"). However, the following real world case:

```
private/* some comment here */classA variableX;
```

is transformed to

```
privateclassZ variableX;
```

which, of course, causes problems.

Is there any way to tell my CompilerUnit.rewrite() call to preserve the original comments?